# shift the values with the nearest match

Tags: r

How to shift the Start values in `df1` based on the nearest match in Position value of `df2`

```
x <- "Sample    Chromosome  Start
       Samp.1        6  14150000
       Samp.1        7  70000
       Samp.1        13 19250000"    
df1 <-read.table(text=x, header=T, sep = "")

x2 <-  "Name     Chromosome Position
         7:50000    7   50000
         7:57670000 7   57670000
         6:14170000 6   14170000
         6:26950000 6   26950000
         6:36950000 6   36950000
        13:19270000 13  19270000
        13:83370000 13  83370000"           
df2 <- read.table(text=x2, header=T, sep="")

output <-  "Sample  Chromosome  Start   
             Samp.1    6     14170000 
             Samp.1    7      50000
             Samp.1   13     19270000"
```

Comment: shift whic columns ? could you be clear ?

Comment: shift df1[,3] with respect to df2[,3] if df1[,2] == df2[,2]

Comment: what do you mean by "shift"? That word has dozens of meanings.

Comment: If this is nearest match, check `?foverlaps` from `data.table`

Comment: shift  means change the value to the nearest match

Answer (score 1):

I guess from your output, you are looking for the closest variation of the position with respect to your start and replace it. Here is how you can do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
merge(df1, df2[,c(2,3)], by = "Chromosome") %>% 
    group_by(Chromosome) %>% 
    filter(min(abs(Start - Position)) == abs(Start - Position)) %>% 
    select(Sample, Chromosome, Position) %>% unique


# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: Chromosome [3]
#
#   Sample Chromosome Position
#   (fctr)      (int)    (int)
# 1 Samp.1          6 14170000
# 2 Samp.1          7    50000
# 3 Samp.1         13 19270000
```

Comment: interesting..but what if there are two close value for position with respect to start value..for e.g..  in the output, the first segment   14170000, because this is the closest value to  14150000. What if there are two values present in the position,  14130000 and  14170000.